# How to handle an unexpected exception in usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-interface, error-handling

Suppose a wpf App consists essentially of several tabitems each with a rich usercontrol. All usercontrols are in the same UI thread and an unexpected and unhandeld error will crash the App.

Is there a way to avoid this and limit the crash to the particular usercontrol where it occured? And the user can continue on the other tabs.

One way would be to use a separate window on a different thread instead of a tabitem.

Comment: No the UI cannot be separated into several threads. Post the relevant code and XAML where this is happening. And no, the UI shouldn't cause your application to crash under normal circumnstances.

Comment: Might try a Page in each tab an error handler on the Page that disables the Page.  Give an example of an unhandled exception that is crashing the app.

Comment: @Blam: as an example please just consider `throw new Exception()` after a Button click (without a catch, it is supposed to be unexpected). How could the Page catch that in a generic way?

Comment: Are these your usercontrols?  Are you throwing the the new Exception?  I would more looking for a code sample than a "consider".

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), although usually at this stage, something has gone badly wrong and this event is normally handled in order to log error details and/or close the program gracefully:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += MainWindow_UnhandledException;

...

public void MainWindow_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // An unhandled Exception has been thrown
}
```

It will catch all `Exception`s that you have not handled manually. However, there is often only minimal information apart from the `StackTrace` as to exactly where the `Exception` was thrown. Give it a go and see if it helps you.

Comment: I am sorry, it doesn't help, I was looking to handle UnhandledException just for a specific usercontrol, which is not possible.